# How to recommend a shop to buy something?

Tags: grammar, questions

When someone ask "Where can I buy a book ?", and I know a shop around the corner, can I say "look it's in the shop around the corner"?

Is this correct or what is the best way to say it ?

Comment: Saying, “Look, it’s in the shop around the corner” could be construed as a little bit rude or condescending.

Answer (score 1):

No, that doesn't make total sense. A correct version of what you are trying to say would be "You can find a book in the shop around the corner".

Comment: If you're responding to a question about where to find books you don't need to say "you can find a book" in your answer. "In the shop around the corner." is fine.

Comment: I’d likely say, “You could try the shop around the corner.”

Comment: Or "There's a bookshop round the corner."